# Mistake in proof of transitivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a problem from Velleman's *How to prove it*.

Suppose $A$ is a set, and $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$. Let $R = \{ (a,b) \in A \times A \text{ } | \text{ } \text{for every } X \subseteq A \backslash \{a,b \}, \text{if } X \cup \{a\} \in \mathcal{F} \text{ then } X \cup \{b\} \in \mathcal{F} \}$. Show that $R$ is transitive.

My proof seems to be similar and yet somewhat shorter than the hint given at the back. I'm sure I have a mistake somewhere since the hint suggests considering the two cases $b \in X$ and $b \notin X$, but I really can't seem why.

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be arbitrary. Suppose that $a,b,c \in A$ and that $a R b$ and that $b R c$. Let $X$ be an arbitrary set and suppose $X \subseteq A \backslash \{a,c\}$ and $X \cup \{a\} \in \mathcal{F}$. Since $a R b$  and $X \cup \{a\} \in \mathcal{F}$ then $X \cup \{b\} \in \mathcal{F}$. But since $b R c$ and $X \cup \{b\} \in \mathcal{F}$ then $X \cup \{c\} \in \mathcal{F}$. This shows that if $a R b$ and $b R c$ it follows that $a R c$, hence $R$ is transitive.

Comment: The definition of $R$ considers only subsets that contain neither $a$ nor $b$. In your argument, $X\cup \{a\} \in \mathcal{F}$ doesn't guarantee $(X\setminus \{b\}) \cup \{a\} \in \mathcal{F}$, which is what you need to conclude $X\cup \{b\} \in \mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that you argued as if the constraint $X\subseteq A\setminus\{a,b\}$ in the definition of $R$ were the same in each case, but it isn't.